# Possible to make a jquery hide function run until the item it is hiding is ready to be viewed or modify a slider to be more intelligent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I have a page with a pdf that gets displayed inside a slider.  When it's loaded it's fantastic however it looks a touch ugly until that point as the scroll arrows will be on screen but the dimensions of the slider haven't yet been established so it's all bunched up.

I created a white div that was larger than the pdf and targeted it with a  jquery function that after a certain amount of time would hide and reveal the pdf underneath.

Th problem is that some pdf's take longer than others to load.  I don't want someone to have to wait 5 seconds when only 1 may be needed and I also don't want someone to wait 5 seconds only to then see the 'mess' that I was trying to hide as that pdf may take longer to load especially taking net speed into account.

What I'd like is either for the function to know when it should hide or a way for the slider to be 'better', possibly already knowing the size of the page, loading the first and then while that it being read the others could be loaded in the background?

Any ideas / help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Iframe with an onload event handler?

Comment: I've used the accordion quite a lot, would they work together?